# Is there an algorithm to switch from classical notation to concatenative stack-based notation?

Tags: algorithms, programming-languages, combinatory-logic

Reading a bit about [Joy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joy_(programming_language)), I was wondering if there wasn't an algorithm to switch from classical notation and style to concatenative and stack-based style.

Of course, for simple mathematical expressions without variables, for example, you just have to convert the expression into the inverted Polish form:

```
f = 3 + 5 * (7 - 1) / 2

→

f = 3 5 7 1 - * 2 / +
```

But what if our function has variables? It's easy to find ourselves the expected result when the expression is simple, like here for example:

```
square(x) = x * x

→

square = dup *
```

But for a more complex function, it becomes almost impossible to reason :

```
-- This is a Haskell code
qsort [] = []
qsort (x:xs) = qsort ys ++ x : qsort zs
    where
        (ys, zs) = partition (< x) xs

→

qsort =
    [small]
    []
    [uncons [>] split]
    [enconcat]
    binrec
```

(According to Wikipedia, in the page linked above.)

So, is there any way to make a computer do this kind of conversion? (Also, should the order of the arguments in a function be reversed?)

I haven't found any algorithm on the Internet that meets these expectations. It seems to me however to have searched well. I also imagine that a conversion like the quick sort function, as shown above, would probably be more complicated to generate, but I mean: the logic behind must be the same as a more simple expression.

My goal would simply be educational, I would be interested in seeing these conversions.

Comment: Sounds like you need a compiler that targets Joy (or similar). These kinds of transformations are usually best done in a more abstract model

Comment: Yes, that's about right actually, because I was thinking of making one toy. So I posted this as accurately as possible, for SE.
On the other hand, what do you mean by "more abstract model"?

Comment: AST transformations are easier than textual, for example.

Comment: Oh, yes, that's obvious indeed. I assumed that everything was in AST form in my question (for an implementation), but to clarify I left it in textual form.

Comment: You're really describing a compiler! The Java virtual machine, for instance, has all local and intermediate values on a stack, and has no variables...